# Como usar mais de um caractere de separação no método split()?

Tags: java, string, regex, java-8

Eu gostaria de quebrar uma `String` em várias substrings, para isto estou usando o método `split()`. Acontece que, eu não tenho certeza de quais caracteres podem estar na variável que utilizarei.

Exemplificando:

```
String words[] = line.split(" ");
```

Este código atende ao que estou precisando, estou considerando que será usado somente o `"  "` para separar as palavras. Mas o problema é que essa entrada será lida de um arquivo de texto onde usuário pode colocar qualquer caractere entre as palavras.

Então, eu precisaria criar algo do tipo:

```
String words[] = line.split(" #@_\\/.*");
```

É possível fazer isto em Java? Alguma solução?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é:

```
    String a = "Exemplo, de. separar- string+ por* carater";
    //Como quer todos os caracteres pode usar esta expressão regular:
    String[] parts = a.split("[\\W]");

    for(String i:parts){
        System.out.println("===" +i);
    }
```

*Output:*

```
run:
===Exemplo
===
===de
===
===separar
===
===string
===
===por
===
===carater
```

Para remover os espaços também deverá alterar esta linha de código:

```
String[] parts = a.split("[\\W][ ]");
```

*Output:*

```
===Exemplo
===de
===separar
===string
===por
===carater
```

Comment: Funcionou! Poderia explicar melhor o que o `[\\W]` significa ali?

Comment: @mxn Em expressões regulares `\W` significa qualquer caractere que não seja uma letra ou número ou um *underline*.

Comment: obrigado utluiz, estava a procura dessa informação para juntar a resposta

Comment: @mxn repara que editei a expressão regular assim `[\\W][ ]` assim remove os espaços também, como estava `[\\W]` guarda os espaços também...

Comment: A edição que você fez deixou de funcionar: `a.split("[\\W][ ]");` não funciona. `a.split("[\\W]");` funciona. O resultado de `a.split("[\\W][ ]");` é o mesmo postado pelo @bigown. Tem como editar e deixar como estava?

Comment: eu estou a executar este código, para ver se estava correto(por isso detetei os espaços) mas curioso que comigo funcionou direito

Comment: No meu caso não funcionou. Se possível, deixe as duas implementações então, pois somente a primeira deu certo aqui.

Comment: é muito estranho, mas sim vou fazer essa edição...

Answer (score 14):

## Solução com `\W`

Nas expressões regulares implementadas no Java, conforme [documentação da classe `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), existe uma classe de caracteres `\w` (minúsculo), que **representa os caracteres que formam palavra**. Seria o mesmo que `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

Existe também a classe de caracteres `\W`(maiúsculo), que representa o oposto da anterior, isto é, caracteres que não formam palavras.

Uma solução simplista seria usar o `\W` para quebrar a String por qualquer caractere que não seja de uma palavra, incluindo qualquer pontuação e espaço.

Mas há problemas com esta abordagem:

- **Não considera caracteres especiais** que comumente fazem parte de palavras, como é o caso do hífen, por exemplo.
- **Não considera caracteres acentuadas** pois eles não fazem parte do conjunto de caracteres de palavras do `\w`.

## Solução específica

Uma solução mais específica seria definir um conjunto de caracteres que devem "quebrar" a String. Exemplo:

```
String caracteres = " #@_\\/.*";
```

Depois, você coloca esses caracteres entre colchetes, o que em expressões regulares significa uma classe personalizada de caracteres. Exemplo:

```
String words[] = line.split("[" + Pattern.quote(caracteres) + "]");
```

O método `Pattern.quote` acima garante que os caracteres receberão o *escape* necessário para não estragar a expressão regular.

## Exemplo completo

```
String line = "1 2#3@4_5/6.7*8";
String caracteres = " #@_\\/.*";
String words[] = line.split("[" + Pattern.quote(caracteres) + "]");
for (String string : words) {
    System.out.print(string + " ");
}
```

Saída:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

## Caracteres especiais em sequência

Com a expressão acima, podem ficar palavras em branco no vetor, caso sejam encontrados dois caracteres especiais ou espaços em sequência. Isso é comum no caso de uma frase que contém um ponto final ou vírgula seguido de um espaço em branco.

Para evitar que isso aconteça, basta acrescentar um `+` à direta da classe personalizada para que o `split` capture a sequência de caracteres especiais num único bloco, de uma só vez. Exemplo:

```
String words[] = line.split("[" + Pattern.quote(caracteres) + "]+");
```

Answer (score 6):

Acho que isto resolve seu problema:

```
import java.io.*;

 class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String line = new String("banana*batata.pepino#alface_tomate@cenoura cebola/abacate|morango\\laranja");
      for (String retval: line.split(" |#|@|_|\\\\|\\/|\\.|\\*") ){
         System.out.println(retval);
      }
    
   }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Tay2qi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pjyknlyn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/SplitRegEx.java).

Estou usando um operador *or* do RegEx afinal o `split()` é [baseado em RegEx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Não sei se o RegEx está certo porque não costumo usá-lo mas é basicamente isto.

Comment: Não funcionou para mim. Ele gerou uma `String` vazia, não sei o que foi "splited" mas não foram os caracteres, hehe. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Tinha um probleminha mesmo mas agora testei e funcionou no que testei.